# Applying Translations to Entire OpenGL ES Scene - iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, opengl-es, 3d, transform

I have an OpenGL ES scene which is made up of about 20 objects. In the render method for each object I have code which scales, rotates and positions (using glmultmatrix) that object in the correct place in each scene (see code below).

My question is how can I then apply a transformation to the entire scene as a whole ? E.g scale / enlarge the entire scene by 2 ?

```
glPushMatrix();
glLoadIdentity();

//Move some objects.

if (hasAnimations) {

    glTranslatef(kBuildingOffset);
    //scale
    glScalef(kModelScale);

    //glMultMatrixf(testAnimation);

    zRotation = kBuildingzRotation
    xRotation = kBuildingxRotation
    yRotation = kBuildingyRotation
    glRotatef(yRotation, 0.0f, 1.0, 0.0f);
    glRotatef(xRotation, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glRotatef(zRotation, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

    //NSLog(@"ANIMATION FRAME IS %d", animationFrame);
    //NSLog(@"MATRICE IS %f", animationArray[0][0]);
    glMultMatrixf(animationArray[animationFrame]);
    //glMultMatrixf(matricesArray);
    glMultMatrixf(matricePivotArray);

    //glMultMatrixf(testAnimation);
}

//First rotate our objects as required.

if ([objectName isEqualToString:@"movingobject1"]) {

    glTranslatef(kFan1Position); 
    glScalef(kModelScale);
    glMultMatrixf(matricesArray);

    glTranslatef(0, 0, 0);

    zRotation +=kFanRotateSpeed;
    yRotation =kyFanFlip;
    xRotation = kxFanRotation;
    glRotatef(zRotation, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glRotatef(yRotation, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glRotatef(xRotation, 1.0f, 0.0, 0.0f);

    glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, -300);

}

if ([objectName isEqualToString:@"movingobject2"]) {

    glTranslatef(kFan2Position);
    glScalef(kModelScale);
    glMultMatrixf(matricesArray);

    glTranslatef(0, 0, 0);

    zRotation +=kFanRotateSpeed;
    yRotation = kyFanFlip;
    xRotation = kxFanRotation;
    glRotatef(-kFan3YOffset, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glRotatef(zRotation, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glRotatef(yRotation, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glRotatef(xRotation, 1.0f, 0.0, 0.0f);
    glRotatef(kFan3YOffset, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

    glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, -300);

}

if ([objectName isEqualToString:@"movingobject3"]) {

    glTranslatef(kFan3Position); 
    glScalef(kModelScale);
    glMultMatrixf(matricesArray);

    glTranslatef(0, 0, 0);

    zRotation +=kFanRotateSpeed;
    yRotation =kyFanFlip;
    xRotation =kxFanRotation;
    glRotatef(-kFan2YOffSet, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glRotatef(zRotation, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glRotatef(yRotation, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glRotatef(xRotation, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glRotatef(kFan2YOffSet, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);

    glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, -300);

}

//Then position the rest of the scene objects.

if (![objectName isEqualToString:@"movingobject1"])
    if (![objectName isEqualToString:@"movingobject2"])
        if(![objectName isEqualToString:@"movingobject3"])
            if (!hasAnimations) {

    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(kBuildingOffset);

//scale
    glScalef(kModelScale);

    zRotation = kBuildingzRotation
    xRotation = kBuildingxRotation
    yRotation = kBuildingyRotation
    glRotatef(yRotation, 0.0f, 1.0, 0.0f);
    glRotatef(xRotation, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glRotatef(zRotation, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

if ([Matrices count]!=0) {
    glMultMatrixf(matricesArray);
}

if (hasPivotNode) {
    glMultMatrixf(matricePivotArray);
}
}

[mesh render];
glPopMatrix();
//restore the matrix
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this easily enough by pushing the transform matrix you desire on to the matrix stack before you do any of your object-specifc transforms, but then *don't* load the identity matrix each time you push another matrix onto the stack. Practically speaking, this will transform all subsequent matrix operations. This is the basic pattern...

```
// Push an identity matrix on the bottom of the stack...
glPushMatrix();
glLoadIdentity();

// Now scale it, so all subsequent transforms will be
// scaled up 2x.
glScalef(2.f, 2.f, 2.f);

foreach(mesh) {

    glPushMatrix();
    //glLoadIdentity(); This will erase the scale set above.
    glDoABunchOfTransforms();
    [mesh render];
    glPopMatrix();
}
```